# C# how to clear the streamwriter buffer without writing to a txt file?

Tags: c#, io

I am working on C# on Win7.

I need to use Streamwriter to write to a txt file.

```
   StreamWriter outfile  = new StreamWriter(MY_PATH, true);
   foreach(a line of strings)
   {
       // process the line
        outfile.Write(String.Format(WIDTH + " " + WIDTH, num1Str+"\t", num2Str+"\t"));

   }
   if all elements in line are "0"
      // do not write anything to the file, clear outfile buffer

   // WIDTH are constants. num1Str and num2Str are variables.
```

How to clear the contents written in the stream buffer ?

Flush is not a solution because I do not want to write the file if all elements are 0.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you missed the point of using `string.Format()`

Comment: what does your forloop do? it looks like it loops the write for fun. Could you please use real code so we can see what depends on what. Because your "a line of string" is used where? do you go char wise? in that case, where do you use the char?

Comment: ok then what is the foreach good for? do you write the same content an X amount of times? num1Str and num2Str is variables of? are they from "a line of string"?

Comment: @Thomas Andreè Lian, num1Str and num2Str are from another data structure.

Comment: then what is your foreach loop doing?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [`outfile.Flush();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:** so now that the question is clearer, you don't want a `StreamWriter`, you want to leverage something like a `MemoryStream` instead. Consider the following snippet:

```
   var writeToDisk = false;
   var outfile  = new MemoryStream();
   foreach(a line of strings)
   {
       // process the line

       // BTW: the `String.Format` you have here is exceptionally confusing
       // and may be attributing to why everything is \0
       outfile.Write(...);

       // set the flag to `true` on some condition to let yourself know
       // you DO want to write
       if (someCondition) { writeToDisk = true; }
   }

   if (writeToDisk)
   {
       var bytes = new byte[outfile.Length];
       outfile.Read(bytes, 0, outfile.Length);
       File.WriteAllBytes(MY_PATH, bytes);
   }
```

Comment: Flush is not a solution because I do not want to write the file if all elements are 0. The contents in the buffer should be removed.

Comment: @user2420472: then you don't want to use a `StreamWriter`. You've already streamed the bytes to disk. Use a `MemoryStream` instead and then if you want to write to disk leverage `File.WriteAllBytes` and feed it the bytes from the `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the `Any` for checking if any is not "0", but also using `using` would be nice so that you can dispose properly.

```
if(someString.Any(a=> a != '0')) //if any elements in line are not '0'
{
    using(StreamWriter outfile  = new StreamWriter(MY_PATH, true))
    {
        foreach(char a in someString)
        {
            outfile.Write(WIDTH + " " + WIDTH, num1Str+"\t", num2Str+"\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But still no check mark on the answer, hate those questions, where they don't accept anything.

Comment: Questions on SO are never "done".  They are not "complete".  They are a constantly evolving and improving collection of knowledge.  The question author finding their solution is merely the *beginning* of a question's journey.  It becoming a canonical resource that is found, used, improved on, and used again by many future visitors is where the real value comes.

Answer (score 1):

> if all elements in line are "0"
>         // do not write anything to the file, clear outfile buffer

Then why don't you check your line's content, before you write it ?

```
// process the line
string line = String.Format(WIDTH + " " + WIDTH, num1Str+"\t", num2Str+"\t");
if(!line.Trim().All(c => c == '0'))
     outfile.Write(line);
```

Comment: trim().all() does not work here, I have numbers such as WIDTH embeded. Thanks

Comment: it should work.If your all numbers are `0` it won't write that line to the file.your line still can contain zeros.

Comment: the trim() only partition by space. there are some numbers in line such as WIDTH, which are constants.