# Proper way to use DisposeAsync on C# streams

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream

I'm writing a method which asynchronously writes separate lines of text to a file. If it's *cancelled* it deletes the created file and jumps out of the loop.

This is the simplified code which works fine... And I marked 2 points which I'm not sure how they are being handled. I want the code to not block the thread in any case.

```
public async Task<IErrorResult> WriteToFileAsync(string filePath,
                                                 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

    foreach (var line in Lines)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //
            // [1] close, delete and throw if cancelled
            //
            writer.Close();
            stream.Close();
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }

        // write to the stream
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(line.ToString());
    }

    //
    // [2] flush and let them dispose
    //
    await writer.FlushAsync();
    await stream.FlushAsync();
    // await stream.DisposeAsync(); ??????
    return null;
}
```

### 1

I'm calling `Close()` on `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` and I think it will run synchronously and blocks the thread. How can I improve this? I don't want to wait for it to flush the buffer into the file and then delete the file.

### 2

I suppose the `Dispose` method will be called and not `DisposeAsync` at the end of the `using` scope. (*is this assumption correct?*).

So `Dispose` blocks the thread and in order to prevent that I'm flushing first with `FlushAsync` so that `Dispose` would perform *less* things. (*to what extent is this true?*)

I could also remove `using` and instead I could write `DisposeAsync` manually in these two places. But it will decrease readability.

If I open the `FileStream` with `useAsync = true` would it automatically call `DisposeAsync` when `using` block ends?

---

Any explanation or a variation of the above code which performs better is appreciated.

Comment: If the `Stream` class was implementing [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable) you could ensure that `DisposeAsync` would be finally called by `await using` the stream. But it doesn't implement this interface...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for the useful info. I didn't know I could do `await using` :)

Comment: Yeap, it is new C# 8 syntax. :-)

Comment: Doh! I mentioned that the `Stream` class doesn't implement the `IAsyncDisposable` based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.0). I should look at the [Object Explorer](https://prnt.sc/psim9n). Unfortunately the online documentation is not updated with the new C# 8 features yet.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes `Stream` implements `IAsyncDisposable` and `await using` pretty much works. maybe the documentation is outdated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you have it, the `using` statement will call `Dispose()`, not `DisposeAsync()`.

C# 8 brought a new `await using` syntax, but for some reason it's not mentioned in the [What's new in C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) article.

But it's [mentioned elsewhere](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2019/09/16/async-streams-look-new-language-features-c-8/).

```
await using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
await using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

But also note that this will only work if:

- You're using .NET Core 3.0+ since that's when [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable?view=netcore-3.0) was introduced, or
- Install the [Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/) NuGet package. Although this only adds the interfaces and doesn't include the versions of the `Stream` types (`FileStream`, `StreamWriter`, etc.) that use it.

Even in the [Announcing .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0/) article, `IAsyncDisposable` is only mentioned in passing and never expanded on.

On another note, <strike>you don't need to do this</strike> (I see why now):

```
writer.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Since [the documentation for `Close` says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.close?view=netcore-3.0)

> This method calls Dispose, specifying `true` to release all resources. You do not have to specifically call the Close method. Instead, ensure that every Stream object is properly disposed.

Since you're using `using`, `Dispose()` (or `DisposeAsync()`) will be called automatically and `Close` won't do anything that's not already happening.

So if you do need to specifically close the file, but want to do it asynchronously, just call `DisposeAsync()` instead. It does the same thing.

```
await writer.DisposeAsync();
```

---

```
public async Task<IErrorResult> WriteToFileAsync(string filePath,
                                                 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    await using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

    foreach (var line in Lines)
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // not possible to discard, FlushAsync is covered in DisposeAsync
            await writer.DisposeAsync(); // use DisposeAsync instead of Close to not block

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }

        // write to the stream
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(line.ToString());
    }

    // FlushAsync is covered in DisposeAsync
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I `Close` the streams because I want to immediately delete the file and `Dispose` occurs too late giving me `it is being used by another process` exception

Comment: Ah, ok. That totally makes sense.

Comment: And I can't find a way to just **discard** what's been written to the buffer so far. So I have to wait for it to flush everything and then throw them away.

Comment: it is not quite true that this is .NET Core 3.0+ - the necessary APIs are available in [`Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/); the *problem* is that `Stream` etc *doesn't implement* this interface yet (before .NET Core 3.0); but in the general sense: the *feature* can work *if* components take the ref and implement the API

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks! I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: `await writer.DisposeAsync()` works when called manually, however it should be called only for one of the streams since the two streams has one common `BaseStream` (?). If I call it for both it gives `Cannot access a closed file.` exception. too much details! :))

Comment: @Bizhan Yeah, that makes sense (only disposing one of them).

Comment: @Bizhan I don't see a way to discard what has been written to the buffer so far without writing it. I looked at [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/ac99a1b7168bd32046a954c3f06012c0fa909bed/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO) and I don't see anything in either `FileStream` or `StreamWriter` that will let you do that.

Comment: I think I should ask that in another question. Thanks for the help, I added the code I come up with according to your answer.

Comment: It has been asked a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376956/close-a-filestream-without-flush) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761947/c-sharp-how-to-clear-the-streamwriter-buffer-without-writing-to-a-txt-file) before. There are lots of answers there, although they pre-date .NET Core.

Comment: By the way, [`DisposeAsync()` will flush the buffer](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/ac99a1b7168bd32046a954c3f06012c0fa909bed/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/FileStream.Windows.cs#L278), so you don't need to call `FlushAsync()` separately.

Comment: @GabrielLuci that's true. I reflected that into the answer as well

Comment: Shouldn't you open the `FileStream` with [`useAsync: true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_Boolean_)?  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404644) to [Why .NET async await file copy is a lot more CPU consuming than synchronous File.Copy() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42403813) as well as https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access suggest to.